# Rigged model and optionals controller (High Quantity Production way)

Tags: workflow

I'm looking for a way to manually control animations and optionals in the most easy way for my clients that have no idea how to use the Blender 2.79 Cycles or have never been into 3D before.

Let's say I've got a 3D modelled car, and my clients want that model rigged with all functioning parts and with all its optionals available.

With that in mind, my workflow nowadays is a mess like this:

- SilverCarBlackRimsBlackInterior.blend
- RedCarBlackRimsBlackInterior.blend
- BlueCarBlackRimsBlackInterior.blend
- SilverCarSilverRimsBlackInterior.blend
- RedCarSilverRimsBlackInterior.blend
- BlueCarSilverRimsBlackInterior.blend

and the list goes infinite with all versions of that car available to offer.

So, since this is humanly possible but really energy-consuming and annoying for me and for my clients, Isn't there an easier way to acchieve this into a simple .blend file?

[image: general model controls]

I made this image just as refferential of what I would be looking for. A simple control or panel where I and my customers can configure the 3D model in the most simple and instant way. Most of my customers don't have time to watch tutorials or are not fully into 3D industry, so this is giving me bad user experience nowadays and I want to improve that issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could certainly write an addon to present a UI like that, but before going that far, have you tried using [custom properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/custom_properties.html) (with [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html))? Perhaps that might meet your needs, to some extent at least.

Comment: No, no idea about Custom Properties or Drivers usage. What limitations or features does it have in this particular case? Thank you!

Comment: Custom properties can only be numeric values. So it's perfect for things like "door open amount", but things like choosing a material not so much. However you could drive values *in* a material, e.g. how many metallic flecks to mix in, etc.

Comment: @gandalf3 in these two days of testing, I've managed to learn to make a "control" that is linked to the doors using Transform. So, that issue would be covered. Now I'm looking a way to control multiple lights with one parameter. Driving values in a material like you said looks way more customizable for the user, and thats exactly what I'm looking for. So, thank you for the advice and going to take a shot about it.

Comment: @gandalf3 I've just learn't about using Drivers, and I can certainly say that all this topic is covered. Testing along with a model using a controller for all those different properties, I was cappable to acchieve good results without a UI like I've posted. So, thank you for your knowledgements, now I'm looking forward to make these parameters easy to use. Thanks again!